# The task includes an option with an undefined variable

Tags: loops, variables, ansible, centos7, firewalld

I have the below vars file and Ansible task which allows some ports for a specific source IPs on the firewall.

But for some reason, whenever I run the task I got this error:

`FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable.`

Even though I'm able to echo out these variables using `debug` Ansible module, so basically I'm just unable to use these variable specifically in this task.

**Ansible Task:**

```js
---
- name:
  firewalld:
    permanent: yes
    port: "{{ item.0 }}"
    state: enabled
    zone: public
    source: "{{ item.1 }}"
    with_nested: 
      - "{{ ports }}"
      - "{{ ips }}"
```

**Vars File:**

```js
ports:
  - "8000/tcp"
  - "9997/tcp"
  - "8181/tcp"
  - "8080/tcp"
  - "8191/tcp"
  - "8088/tcp"
  - "8065/tcp"
  
ips:
  - "192.168.210.30/32"
  - "192.168.210.35/32"
  - "192.168.210.40/32"
  - "192.168.210.31/32"
  - "192.168.210.36/32"
  - "192.168.210.41/32"
  - "192.168.210.42/32"
  - "192.168.210.37/32"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The indentation of *`with_nested`* is wrong. Correct syntax is

```yaml
- name:
  firewalld:
    permanent: yes
    port: "{{ item.0 }}"
    state: enabled
    zone: public
    source: "{{ item.1 }}"
  with_nested: 
    - "{{ ports }}"
    - "{{ ips }}"
```

Comment: Even small space in yaml file makes difference.